# calling a function inside setTimeout and inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, call

basically I have written a function:

```
function animation(){
    setTimeout(
        function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animation); 
        if (player.currentFrame == player.frames) {
            player.currentFrame = 0;
            } else {
            player.currentFrame++;
            }
        }
    , 1000 / 15);
}
```

and I'm trying to call it with this code
`animation(fps);`

I tried making it like this:

```
function animation(fps){
    setTimeout(
        function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animation); 
        if (player.currentFrame == player.frames) {
            player.currentFrame = 0;
            } else {
            player.currentFrame++;
            }
        }
    , 1000 / fps);
}
```

and tried to call it with `animation(30)`
but it didn't work. I tried search topic like this but non of them is excatly what I want.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried this syntax

```
function animation(fbs){
        requestAnimationFrame(animation); 
        if (player.currentFrame == player.frames) {
            player.currentFrame = 0;
        } else {
            player.currentFrame++;
        }        
       setTimeout(function(){animation(fbs) }, 1000 / fbs);
}
```

I changed the code from `setTimeout('animation(fbs)', 1000 / fbs);` to `setTimeout(function(){animation(fbs) }, 1000 / fbs);`

Comment: @JeffShaver : why? . I used it before and working fine with me till now

Comment: @MuhammadOsman 1) it is slower. Basically, setTimeout will have to run `eval()` on it to figure out what you want to do and 2) it runs that funciton in a different scope if you pass in a string, so it is possible to run into issues with parameters being undefined. The correct syntax with no params is `setTimeout(animation, 1000 /fps);` or with params: `setTimeout(function() { animation(param1,param2) }, 1000/fps);`

Comment: hmm.. can you please help me with my question?

Comment: @Nucleus can you try the changes as Jeff said and I edit the answer so please check it.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` will only call the function once after the time has elapsed, so unless you call `animation` again with `fps`, it will simply run once and be done.  You could use `setInterval` to call the function every `1000/fps` milliseconds.

```
var frame = 0;
animation(20);
function animation(fps){
    console.log(fps)
    setInterval(
        function(){
            console.log("A");
            document.getElementById("sp1").innerHTML = frame;
            frame++;
        }
    , 1000 / fps);
}
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Up4Cq/

Or if you want to use setTimeout, you need to call the `animation` function again:

```
function animation(fps){
    console.log(fps)
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            console.log("A");
            document.getElementById("sp1").innerHTML = frame;
            frame++;
           animation(fps);
        }
    , 1000 / fps);
}
```

Here is the fiddle for setTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/Up4Cq/1/

Comment: yea, i'm sure i want setTimeout, does it work with setTimeout too :/?