# JavaScript - 'this' inside setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

My question is related to the following:

[setTimeout() inside JavaScript Class using “this”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this)

[calling a function inside setTimeout and inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810808/calling-a-function-inside-settimeout-and-inside-a-function)

I'm trying to implement a simple animation loop. The draw function is a member function of a state object. I'm having problems getting 'this' to work within the setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame.

I have the following code:

```
ANIM.State.prototype = {
    constructor: ANIM.State,
    play: function(){
        if(!this.paused){
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                requestAnimationFrame(that.play);
                that.setFrameNum(that.currentFrame + 1); //draw code is in here
            }, 1000 / 24);
        }
    }
};
```

However, when I call play(), it runs twice and stops.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd really like to keep this function as a class function, and not a global one, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your issue with `.bind()` like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(that.play.bind(that));
```

The problem is all that is passed to `requestAnimationFrame()` is a reference to the `.play` method and it is then executed as a normal function call so `this` inside it will be wrong and will not point to your object.  This is a common problem when passing a method as a callback where you want it to be called as `obj.method()`.

There are numerous possible work-arounds, but the easiest in modern browsers is to use `.bind()` as I've shown above.  This actually creates a small stub function that then calls `that.play()` rather than just `play()` so that the object reference is used as you need and it's that stub function that is passed to `requestAnimationFrame()`.

You could also do it like this (creating your own stub function), though `.bind()` seems cleaner to me:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    that.play();
});
```